# Can't connect to external IP from local network behind iptables NAT

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nat, proxmox

We have Proxmox vitual environmenet witch couple of virtual machines. Host server have multiple external IP adresses. We use iptables to forward connections to certain external IP+port to selected virtual machine. And we use NAT for outgoing connections from VMs.

So far everything works. Problem occurs when VMs try to connect to host external IP it's not working.

As far as i understand what we need is hairpin NAT (NAT reflection). But we are not able to get it working by instructions we found.

Our iptables rules:

```
# === FIREWALL ===
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [3174:1555907]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [2521:547542]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2753:2039466]
:fail2ban-ssh - [0:0]

# allow returnig packets
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# drop all other
-A INPUT -p tcp -d 1.2.3.4/32 -j DROP

COMMIT

# === NAT ===

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [140854:7345476]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2635:170444]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [25596:1617170]

# INCOMING
-A PREROUTING  -d 1.2.3.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.60.10:80
-A PREROUTING  -d 1.2.3.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.60.10:443
-A PREROUTING  -d 1.2.3.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.60.20:80

# OUTGOING
-A POSTROUTING -d 10.0.60.10 -s 10.0.0.0/16 -p tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to 10.0.0.1
-A POSTROUTING -o vmbr0 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4

COMMIT
```

1.2.3.4 - external IP of host

10.0.60.10, 10.0.60.20 - internal IPs of VMs

10.0.0.1 - internal IP of host

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! I was typo on my side.

This is working solution for hairpin NAT:

```
# === FIREWALL ===
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [3174:1555907]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [2521:547542]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2753:2039466]
:fail2ban-ssh - [0:0]

# allow returnig packets
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# drop all other
-A INPUT -p tcp -d 1.2.3.4/32 -j DROP

COMMIT

# === NAT ===

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [140854:7345476]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2635:170444]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [25596:1617170]

# INCOMING
-A PREROUTING  -d 1.2.3.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.60.10:80
-A PREROUTING  -d 1.2.3.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.60.10:443
-A PREROUTING  -d 1.2.3.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.60.20:80

# OUTGOING
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/16 -d 10.0.0.0/16 -p tcp -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.1
-A POSTROUTING -o vmbr0 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4

COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -s 10.0.0.0/16 -d 1.2.3.4 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Doesn' work either. I already tried similar rule (only with -s 10.0.0.0/16 for all virtual machines)

Comment: then use `iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -s 10.0.0.0/16 -d 1.2.3.4 -j DNAT --to 10.0.60.10` (by mistake)

Comment: This should replace? -A PREROUTING  -d 1.2.3.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.60.10:80

Comment: Point is I also need different rules based on port. It's not in my example, but I need connections to 8080 forwarded to different machine thant connections to 80.